# matplotlib axvline truth ambiguous or list issue?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some vertical lines on a chart that has a "list" of integers (1...300) and some "values" (floats).  The following works when x=[48], but when x is set to x=[48, 83, 155, 292], the following code:

```
pylab.plot(list, values, label='Trend', color='k', linestyle='-')
pylab.axvline(x, linewidth=1, color='g')
```

Generates this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2053, in axvline
    ret = ax.axvline(x, ymin, ymax, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3478, in axvline
    scalex = (xx<xmin) or (xx>xmax) ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What does it mean?  (I thought it was pretty funny that python pretends to knows when truth is ambiguous).  Can I not pass a list to axvline?

Comment: Not related to the problem: `pylab.plot(list, values...` using reserved keyword `list` as a variable identifier actually reassigns class `list` when the variable is set: Try `list = [1, 2, 3]; list2 = list((4,5,6))`, the second assignment won't work as `list` is not anymore a built-in class. [See #5](https://faun.dev/c/stories/realbenjizo/a-beginners-guide-to-variables-in-python/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of multiple calls to `axvline` we can use the plot command itself but providing the correct transformation (this is many times faster if there are many lines):

```
import matplotlib.transforms as tx
ax = pylab.gca()
trans = tx.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
pylab.plot(np.repeat(x, 3), np.tile([.25, .75, np.nan], len(x)), linewidth=2, color='g', transform=trans)
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep a sort of ID for each of the plotted lines? E.g., if `x=[2,4,6]`, then there would be 3 lines. I would then like to be able to remove the line at 4 (i.e., index 1 of `x`). This is in the context of interactive plots.

Answer (score 27):

No, you can't pass a list to `axvline`. For multiple vertical lines within one line, something like this will do

```
[pylab.axvline(_x, linewidth=1, color='g') for _x in x]
```

Answer (score 14):

For completeness, there is also the possibility of using `matplotlib.pyplot`s [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html). This function accepts a list of x-coordinates. Furthermore, you can specify where the lines need to start/end with the arguments `ymin` and `ymax`. In the case of this question the code would be:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(list, values, label='Trend', color='k', linestyle='-')

trans = mt.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
ax.vlines(x, ymin=0, ymax=1, linewidth=1, color='g', transform=trans)
```

Using the `transform` argument makes it easier to have the lines from the top to the bottom of your plot. You can read more about it [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). You can also skip that argument. In that case you have to specify `ymin` and `ymax` in actual y-coordinates.

Comment: I like this answer `vlines` with `transforms` looks like the elegant answer here.

Comment: Even more elegant option is `ax.get_xaxis_transform()` which handles returning the blended transform.

Answer (score 1):

`axvline` is for creating x **vertical** line.

Meaning at a certin x point from y-min to y-max.

`x` cannot be a `list` type.

a simple example:

```
axvline(x=.5, ymin=0.25, ymax=0.75)
```

You can read more [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline)

If you want to create a rectangle you can use:

```
axvspan(xmin, xmax, ymin=0, ymax=1, **kwargs)
```

in your case xmin is 1 and x man is 300.